# Highcharts highstocks - candlestick graph has last value partially cut

Tags: highcharts

In a candlestick graph i am building, the latest bar is cut-off partially such that even the bar is not visible. Thus it's difficult to judge the high and low by seeing the bar.

I'm unable to post a pic now but it's like the last rectangle being cut in half.

I'm tried a lot of options in the api but can't figure out why this is not showing correctly. The chart margin and axis offset options havent' helped. Is there a way i can set the series margin from the plot area so that it displays right.

Comment: Could you reproduce your chart in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/anurag7/E2ryg/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, the best solution is to insert a dummy series which should be hidden from every aspect of the chart. So try this, insert a dummy series from the last point of the data series to some extra buffer(as per need). Then remove this series from the chart by explicitly removing it from the legends (using showinlegend),chart(setting linewidth to 0) and from tooltip by having a check in formatter. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure it out, because no matter how I changed the xAxis.maxPadding or changed the xAxis.max, it would always cut off the last candlestick when I clicked on the range selector.

To solve it, (hack) I just added an extra data point in my series and set it 1 day past the last day and set all values to null.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code or a pic, it's hard to tell the problem, but it sounds like you need to use the max padding option. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding. You may also want to look at endOnTick as well as whether you are setting max on the axis.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/anurag7/E2ryg/3/  The last stick is only partially visible in the 1Y range.. The extent varies and at times even the high/low line is not visible. I've tried using maxPadding and minPadding to 0 and other values but it remains the same.